# How does "this" in work in Java when calling a method?

Tags: java, android

How does `this.C()` work exactly? method C is non-static so it has to be called via an instance. this refers to the current object but what object and how is it created? I didn't explicitly create an object so does compiling implicitly creates one behind the scene?...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.C();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id ==R.id.action_search){
            this.openSearch();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
           // openSettings();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message= editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
   public void C(){
}
    public void openSearch(){
        getActionBar().hide();
    }

}
```

Comment: Compiling != executing code.

Comment: If you didn't create an object, then the method isn't being called. Analogy: just because the architect drew up blueprints doesn't mean the house is built.

Comment: How are you even calling B?

Comment: Sorry that is a bad example, i am learning android programming and i dont see where in my main class are we creating an instance. onCreate() kind of acts like main right? But nowhere did i create something like MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity()

Comment: We can't answer a question using a bad example. Find the minimal code that reproduces your problem. Note, too, when you're using frameworks (such as the Android SDK) they may be instantiating classes as part of what they do. Do you declare this activity somewhere? Good chance other code may be instantiating it, then.

Comment: You may also want to check at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html and the following two sections.

Comment: @user2644819 The Android system creates the new activity and call the corresponding methods..

Comment: For Android when you start an activity for the first time  the onCreate is the "constructor" that is called automatically by android. This is where you initialize everything for the first time as well as initialize the view. you should read the following : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: edited question with code to reflect

Comment: @Parnit ah okay, that makes a lot of sense. I'm only on the "Supporting different devices" so i didn't get that far yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android when you start an activity for the first time, the onCreate is called by the Android OS. This is where you should write code to initialize all your views and variable. In the case of this.c() -or just c() - Android will automatically call it since it is in the onCreate  method. Also since c() is part of the class, the instance of the class at run time is referred by "this" implicitly.

I recommend understanding  life cycle of android apps. it  will help you with developing good apps. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Comment: good information but just to make sure i understand, how exactly is the object created? There is nothing in the code i provided that creates an object. Normally when you compile and run code, main is called where you create an object using the new keyword. The constructor of that class then gets called(a lot like how onCreate gets called). But again i didn't create an object, so is it done automatically behind the works?

Comment: If you open your Manifest file and look at the MainActivity section you should see the following under it:   `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>`  This indicates that when the application is opened, that MainActivity will be the first activity called thus causing the onCreate function to get excuted and create the instance of that activity.

Comment: so the onCreate() method is what creates the instance? onCreate() sounds a lot like the class's constructor but a constructor doesn't actually create an instance, it just initializes stuff.

Comment: From the link section Creating a New Instance, "the system creates every new instance of Activity by calling its onCreate() method." In Java, a constructor is used to create an instance of the class.

Comment: " In Java, a constructor is used to create an instance of the class" - i thought the "new" keyword is what created the instance of the class?

Comment: oh ok. I was referring to the whole statement "new Object()". My bad.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I understand your question correctly.

In the `onCreate` method you already have a `this` pointer, it is given when it is called. It is not sure where the caller gets it from, and it does not matter anyway.

Comment: Hi, please let me know what is wrong with my answer so I can improve it! -cheers